# Python bluetooth returns nothing (Raspberry PI)

Tags: python, bluetooth

I got the following code:

```
import bluetooth


def apparaat():
    nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True, flush_cache = True, duration = 15)
    for address in nearby_devices:
        print("Gevonden apparaten: " + str(address))
    print("Gevonden apparaten: " + str(nearby_devices))
apparaat()
```

When I run the script the out put is:

```
Gevonden apparaten: []
```

When I scan for bluetooth devices on my raspberry PI it returns a couple. What im a missing here?

Comment: did you install pi-bluetooth? sudo apt-get install pi-bluetooth

Comment: Yes I did :(! (thanks for helping me)

Comment: How do you scan for bluetooth devices when it returns a couple?

Comment: The default software on the raspberry PI. Did click on it when ADD device and now the Raspberry starts scanning all the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to run this code? I found that someone ported this bluetooth package from python 2.7 to 3.x and it might have introduced some bugs when printing unicode strings.

```
import bluetooth
x = bluetooth.discover_devices()
n = bluetooth.lookup_name(x[0])
print(n)
```

(source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pybluez/Kq-ViMBo6es)

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, when I run this code I get the following error:
BluetoothError: Error communicating with local bluetooth adapter. Trying to figer out what it means

Comment: After the reboot of the bluetooth service I get the error: No such devics lol

Comment: Are you not using it with other software at the same time?
Hint: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Bluetooth-InOut-Board-or-Whos-Hom/?ALLSTEPS

maybe try 
"wget https://pybluez.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/simple/inquiry.py
python inquiry.py"